# Should the name of an array of objects in json be pluralized or not

Tags: json

What is the convention,should array of objects in json be pluralized or not

i.e

```
{
    "releases": [
       {
           "id": "0b405ea7-8785-402f-bcf7-d55f5000dc3e",
           "title": "Wintertunes"
       },
       {
           "id": "7eb37a3a-646d-4501-a373-e9071186b88d",
           "title": "Adventure Magic Supreme Journey Music"
       }
    ],
}
```

versus

i.e

```
{
    "release": [
       {
           "id": "0b405ea7-8785-402f-bcf7-d55f5000dc3e",
           "title": "Wintertunes"
       },
       {
           "id": "7eb37a3a-646d-4501-a373-e9071186b88d",
           "title": "Adventure Magic Supreme Journey Music"
       }
    ],
}
```

Comment: Usually, I would pluralize it for good style.

Comment: was expecting a few more opinions on this :(

Comment: It's only style - the pluralization or not doesn't affect the functionality. If you choose not to pluralize it then there is nothing that I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of any strong opinion decided to pluralize it

Answer (score 5):

I believe [Google JSON Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsoncstyleguide.xml?showone=Singular_vs_Plural_Property_Names#Singular_vs_Plural_Property_Names) is a good source for this kind of doubt.

> Arrays usually contain multiple items, and a plural property name reflects this.

Also, the strongest argument for the plural form would be the direct object mapping you get from [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). You probably want your `Javascript` code to deal with pluralized array objects.

Though, in case you have a million such entries - with no compression - that extra 's' will for sure produce some significant bloat :P